# Raspberry Pi as iBeacon receiver

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, ibeacon

I have to make a iBeacon reciever for my Raspberry Pi and I have tried to follow this guide: http://www.switchdoc.com/2014/08/ibeacon-raspberry-pi-scanner-python/

The problem is that when I try the command: sudo python testblescan.py

I get the following message: "python: can't open file 'testblescan.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

I'm accessing the Raspberry Pi through PuTTY.

Comment: Where do you put the file? Use `pwd` command to see your current location. Perhaps the didn't matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the instructions exactly then `testblescan.py` should be in the `blescanner` sub-directory of your home directory. Try

```
cd ~/blescanner
```

before you attempt to run the program. Then the Python interpreter should be able to find it.

If for some reason the program has ended up in another directory then you will need to `cd` to that instead.